# ".indexOf" an array of Custom Objects

Tags: arrays, swift2, indexof

In my app I have an array of custom Objects.The structure of each row looks like this when I append them:

```
self.listOfParticipants.append(ParticipantInfo(participantUser: "userID", participantName: "userName", participantIconName: partiImage!))
```

I know that to return the index from a simple array of Strings I could do something like `array.indexOf("Jason")` and would return me the index where "Jason" is.

But what if in my case I want to know the index where the "xxxxx" userID is? I tried the following line, but Xcode doesn't like it:

```
var adminIndex = listOfParticipants.indexOf(ParticipantInfo.participantUser: "xxxxx")
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the duplicate question, see the `indexOf` variant that takes a closure as an argument. Something like `listOfParticipants.indexOf({ $0.participantUser == "xxxxx"})` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen all the answers in the linked post but the right one for my case. Now I found it. Thank you